# How can I create a QR code to open a pop-up review form?

Tags: qr-code

I'm trying to link a QR code to some code, so that when one of my client scan the QR code, in addition to open the notice page, it open the pop up to write an opinion and a mark.

But I can't find a way to create a QR code that would launch a program to do so.

I already succed to create a QR code that leads to the notice page, but not one that automaticaly opens an opinion redaction.

Comment: Your notice page would have the responsibility to show a popup, nothing to do with the QR code.

Comment: As already mentioned, QR codes can not be programmable. But you can force (nudge) client to use your app, by making the data valueless unless they use your app, where you are in control. Example: instead of your QR containing `http://my.site/XYZ987`, you could simply have `XYZ987`. Without knowing full URL, the code is just a string. However, you can't prevent the curious from finding that URL, and possibly modifying it.